# Run HttpClient PostAsync in another Class from MainWindow Background worker?

Tags: c#

Preface: I'm a hobbyist so pardon my ignorance please ;-)
I'm trying to perform a web based multifunction task (online astrometry plate solving) that is located in a separate Class from my main window.  I would like to do this in the background to keep the main window active (for logging messages in a scrolling LogTextBox).
In my Main Window I call this:

```
  public void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
                Astrometry ast = new Astrometry();
                ast.OnlineSolve(GlobalVariables.SolveImage);
         }
```

And in the Astrometry Class it stops at the await httpClient.PostAsync(... 
returns to main window and nothing else happens

```
class Astrometry
    {

 public void OnlineSolve(string image)
        {
            GetSession(apikey);
        }

 private async void GetSession(string apikey)
            {
          ...misc code
                 using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(input, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseAddress, contentPost))
                        {
                            string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                               ...more stuff
                 }
                }
```

I'm wondering if this is just not possible to do this way...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using async/await, you must make sure to always propagate the tasks.

```
public async Task OnlineSolve(string image)
{
  await GetSession(apikey).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async Task GetSession(string apikey)
{
      ...misc code
  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
  {
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(input, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseAddress, contentPost).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
      string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
      ...more stuff
    }
  }
}
```

and again in the worker:

```
public async void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  Astrometry ast = new Astrometry();

  await ast.OnlineSolve(GlobalVariables.SolveImage);
}
```

The main rule is *don't break the await chain*. As soon as you break it, you lose track of the asynchronous operation, and you lose your operation to wait for the result and handle any errors.

Also note that since you're using pure asynchronous I/O, you don't really need to use a background worker in the first place. Just run the asynchronous method directly from your button click handler or whatever, and you'll be fine. If you need to do some CPU work as well, `Task.Run` is a decent option. I'm not even sure if background worker handles marshalling the `await` back to the proper thread correctly (**EDIT:** And indeed, it doesn't; so there really isn't any point in using `BackgroundWorker` with `await`, it's just confusing - just use `Task.Run` for CPU work, and `await` for asynchronous I/O).

The thing to keep in mind is that `await` basically functions as a magical `return` (similar to a `yield return`, if you've ever used that). As soon as execution reaches an `await` that awaits a task that isn't complete, the method `return`s a `Task` (if possible). That's the point where the caller gets flow control back - and if you don't use `await` in the caller, that's the state the work is in when your caller continues execution. Sometimes, this is desirable - for example, when launching multiple tasks in parallel. Usually, you just want to `await` all asynchronous methods immediately.

Comment: Thank you!  worked great and I took your advise and eliminated the background worker.

Comment: @Luaan: FYI, background worker will exit at the first yielding `await`. The `DoWork` resumes on a thread pool thread. I find this behavior confusing (i.e., completed is fired "early"), so I recommend `Task.Run` over BGW, if you even need it. Which of course you don't in this case.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yeah, I kind of expected something like that would happen. The only way it could have worked would be if it used its own synchronization context, which would be kind of pointless *without* the awaits. I'll add it to the answer.